# SSIS send Email with error records using send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Hi I’m trying to send an email of the error records to the team from my package using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail using the Batch ID that is being generated by the package.
My query runs when it’s written in this format:

> @query = 'SELECT BatchID, ErrorRecord FROM dbo.ErrorLog where
>   BatchID = (select Max(BatchID) from dbo.ErrorLog)'

But I want to this using the parameter mapping so I can just get the records for that particular BatchID that is being generated using execute sql task in SSIS.
My query looks like this:

> @query = 'SELECT BatchID, ErrorRecord FROM dbo.ErrorLog   where
>   BatchID = ?'

I mapped the ‘$package::BatchID’ in the parameter mapping of execute sql task. 
  But still for some reason this query does not seem to pick up any error rows.
 Can you help me fix this issue.

Comment: Can you put a picture about how are you setting the parameter....

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was the query was not detecting the "?".
So I created a new variable MailQuery as a string variable in SSIS and passed the query as

> "SELECT BatchID, ErrorRecord FROM dbo.ErrorLog where BatchID ="+(DT_WSTR, 10)@[$Package::BatchID]

In Execute sql task in the Parameter mapping put this new variable.
In SQL statement write

> @query = ?

Now the task works completely fine.